# IF multiple criteria with VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, if-statement, formula, vlookup

I cant fix my formula. Or better i dont even know if im on right way.
My geal is: row B is empty, there will be formula.

```
    A    B    C    D
1  ID   TYPE       ID_Criteria
2   1   FIRM       4
3   0   HUMAN
4   3   FIRM
5   4   CORPORATE
```

IF A2 > 0 then VLOOKUP in row D, if false B2 is FIRM. Otherwise IF A2 > 0 then VLOOKUP in row D and TRUE B2 is CORPORATE. And last condition when A2 < 0, row return Human.

My formula:

```
=IF(A2>0,IF((VLOOKUP(A2,D1:D4,1,0),"CORPORAT","FIRM"),"HUMAN"))
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: You need to use smallerequal, instead of just smaller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
=IF(A2>0,IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A2,$D$1:$D$4,0)),"CORPORATE","FIRM"),"HUMAN")
```

[image]